# Cropping square area around digit which may lie anywhere in a rectangle area

Tags: python, opencv

I've got a rectangular area (white background), where the digit (black) may lie anywhere inside it. When I pass this image into an MNIST model, the predictions aren't as good since the digit gets compressed. I'd like to crop out a square just around the digit.

Does OpenCV have any functions for this? Is it possible to detect the first non-white pixel horizontally so I can crop out the area starting at that pixel instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using the [`boundingRect`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga103fcbda2f540f3ef1c042d6a9b35ac7) function from OpenCV. Therefore, you just have to inverse your input image, so that you have black background and white digits.

Let's have a look at the following code snippet:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Set up test image, white background, black letter with anti-aliasing
img = 255 * np.ones((50, 50), np.uint8)
cv2.putText(img, 't', (20, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1.0, 0, 3, cv2.LINE_AA)

# Generate inverse image (black background, white letter)
inv = 255 - img

# Detect bounding rectangle for any non-zero pixels
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(inv)

# Generate cropped image from obtained parameters
crop = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

# Output
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('crop', crop)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The test image `img` looks like this:

[image: img]

And, the cropped image `crop` looks like this:

[image: crop]

Now, of course, the image is not square, as you requested. So, further work needs to be done to get the maximum of `w` and `h` and crop the sub image properly. Furthermore, you have to check for not violating image borders, etc. That's all some effort I will leave to you. :-)

Hope that helps!